# How to get all slave nodes running in Hadoop cluster and resource available on it using Java Code

Tags: java, hadoop

i was searching the way to find all the slave nodes available in Hadoop cluster but not succeeded. So finally what i tried is, i wrote a Java code to read the slaves file present below path

```
*$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/slaves* (Am using hadoop-2.2.0),
```

using Simple Java Code:

```
BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String slaveNode="";

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/slaves"));

            while ((slaveNode = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(slaveNode);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

but i need the method from which i can get the slave nodes present and resource available on it.Please help me here..